# How to create a list of a given key from dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I want to create a list that holds all dictionary values mapped to a given key.
I only know how to extract values from topmost key, like so:

```
>>> dict1 = {"key1": 1, "key2":2, "key3": 3}
>>> list1 = dict1.values()
>>> print(list1)
dict_values([1, 2, 3])
>>> 
>>> 
>>> dict2 = {"key1": {"id": 1, "val": 100}, "key2": {"id": 2, "val": 200}}
>>> list2 = dict2.values()
>>> print(list2)
dict_values([{'id': 1, 'val': 100}, {'id': 2, 'val': 200}])
```

I want to be able to extract all values from dict2 that are mapped to key = "id".
in this case:

```
[1, 2]
```

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop over the `values` and for each one, lookup based on the `'id'` key

```
>>> [d['id'] for d in  dict2.values()]
[1, 2]
```